# Size of the set of formal power series?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, power-series, formal-power-series

I just need to verify this for self-study:

Claim: The set of all power series in one variable with rational coefficients is not countable.

Proof: That set is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ since a formal power series can be encoded as a sequence of rationals, so it is uncountable.

Is that correct?

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: Seems OK to me also, aside how much detail might be needed (e.g. may have to explain why the set of sequences of rationals is uncountable). Probably best not to use the word "isomorphic" (unless it's the word used in your text/class), because "isomorphic" suggests you might be making some kind of statement about preservation of operations or relations (addition, multiplication, order, etc.) that $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb N$ are associated with. Better is something like "has the same cardinality as" or "is equinumerous to" or "isomorphic as sets" (the last if you still want to use "isomorphic").

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro At least, the obvious bijection is an isomorphism between additive groups